# HTML Email template Table not pushing to bottom when mobile

Tags: html, css

Hihi community how are you?

I'm trying to build my own HTML Email templates but I'm not able to acheive something when talking about responsiveness

This first email is showing when it's a desktop device
[image: desktop device]

But when I switch to mobile I need that does things around {{}} goes down like this

[image: mobile wanted]

But all I'm getting is just that the first  gets smaller when the text it's bigger and the second  not being pushed down

[image: mobile expected]

Can anyone help me with the css?? Im posting it right below

```
.tg {
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
width: 100%;
margin: 32px auto 32px;
}
.tg td{
overflow:hidden;
word-break:normal;
}
.tg .tg-3z1b{
text-align:right;
vertical-align:top;
font-weight: normal;
}
.tg .tg-73oq{
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top
}
.main-content-table {
margin: 64px auto;
}

 <table class="tg">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq" style="width: 50%">Carga de Saldo</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b" style="width: 50%">{{saldo}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Total</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{total}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Saldo Total</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{saldoTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Fecha</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{fecha}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">C&oacute;digo de Operaci&oacute;n</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{qExitosos}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media query to design based on screen width.

This is tested with Papercut email client. Not all email clients are supported.

```html
<style>
.tg {
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
width: 100%;
margin: 32px auto 32px;
}
.tg td{
overflow:hidden;
word-break:normal;
display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .tg td{
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
.tg .tg-3z1b{
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .tg .tg-3z1b{
        text-align: right;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
.tg .tg-73oq{
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top
}
.main-content-table {
margin: 64px auto;
}
</style>

<table class="tg">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq" style="width: 50%">Carga de Saldo</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b" style="width: 50%">{{saldo}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Total</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{total}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Saldo Total</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{saldoTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">Fecha</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{fecha}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-73oq">C&oacute;digo de Operaci&oacute;n</td>
        <td class="tg-3z1b">{{qExitosos}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Small screen]

[image: Large screen]

Not all email clients are accept [media queries](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=media+queries). So, I recommend you to use the super very simple design to make it display the same on most email clients.

Comment: there are a lot of email clients that are actually not acepting media queries yet :(

Comment: In that case, you have to cut off media query responsive design and make it super simple design to display the same on all clients.

Comment: @Andres Maybe use something like `<p>Total<br>{{total}}</p>` instead because that is very simple and supported in all clients.

Comment: But that wouldn't be correct for the desktop part

Comment: @Andres It's because you can't force them to allowed/supported what you want to do, then you have to change your design to be something that is supported in most clients. You have few choices to do. 1. Use media queries to match your need but not support in many email clients or 2. Change your design to be more simple to support in most clients.

Comment: Yes, that's what I though @vee thanks for the help